# R: Error in new_quosures(NextMethod()) : could not find function "new_quosures"

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, quosure

Consider a data frame:

```
data = data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
              b=c("apples", "oranges", "apples", "apples", "apples", "grapefruit"),
              c=c(12, 22, 22, 45, 67, 28), 
              d=c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"),
              out = c(12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22),
              rate = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.07, 0.06))
```

I am trying to group_by and summarize however, I keep getting the error

```
Error in new_quosures(NextMethod()) : 
  could not find function "new_quosures"
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
model.data.dim.names <-  c("a", "b", "c")

data2 <- data %>% group_by_(.dots = model.data.dim.names) %>% summarise(
    mean_adj1 = (mean(out, na.rm=FALSE)),
    mean_adj2 = (mean(out)/mean(rate))
  )
```

Please note, this is dummy data and the error is reproduced in the windows OS with the dummy data. Additionally, I am working on Windows OS. Additionally, I have tried the following:

1. Remove plyr
2. Check and edit the NA/ Infinite values
3. Turning data frame to data table and running the code

Could you please help me understand the root cause of the error or an alternative that I could use?

```
Answer: 

1) tidyr library screws up with it. Removing tidyr helps
2) use most updated dplyr library and group_by/ group_by_at/group_by(!!!syms(model.data.dim.names) works
```

Comment: You likely have an out of date `dplyr` package (which is different from `plyr`) with an updated `rlang` package (or maybe visa versa). Can you show the package version information from `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group-by_` function is deprecated, the current tidyeval way to do this would be to convert the character vector to symbols and then unquote splice them into `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(!!!syms(model.data.dim.names)) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean_adj1 = mean(out, na.rm=FALSE),
    mean_adj2 = mean(out) / mean(rate)
  )
## A tibble: 6 x 5
## Groups:   a, b [4]
#      a b              c mean_adj1 mean_adj2
#  <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1 apples        12        12     1200 
#2     1 apples        22        16      533.
#3     1 oranges       22        14      700 
#4     2 apples        45        18      450 
#5     2 apples        67        20      286.
#6     3 grapefruit    28        22      367.
```

Comment: It gives the same error: "Error in new_quosures(NextMethod()) : 
  could not find function "new_quosures""

Comment: Make sure you have the most recent versions of dplyr and rlang

Answer (score 1):

We could use the `group_by_at` from `dplyr` which can take a string as input

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by_at(model.data.dim.names) %>% 
   summarise(
    mean_adj1 = mean(out, na.rm=FALSE),
    mean_adj2 = mean(out) / mean(rate)
  )
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   a, b [4]
#      a b              c mean_adj1 mean_adj2
#  <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1 apples        12        12     1200 
#2     1 apples        22        16      533.
#3     1 oranges       22        14      700 
#4     2 apples        45        18      450 
#5     2 apples        67        20      286.
#6     3 grapefruit    28        22      367.
```

Comment: It gives the same error: "Error in new_quosures(NextMethod()) : 
  could not find function "new_quosures""

Comment: @BruceWayne  What is the version of `dplyr` you have?  I have `packageVersion('dplyr')#[1] ‘0.8.0.1’`.  `group_by_at` is a new function

Comment: @BruceWayne not sure about the issue.  It is working fine for me

Comment: tidyr library screws up with it. Removing tidyr helps

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same error with code that worked fine just 2 weeks ago. It occurred when applying `dplyr::group_by()`. I had dplyr package version 0.7.6 and updated it to 0.8.0.1. This has solved the problem.